# Can .NET MVC return Control from Controller's Action?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I'm new to MVC and I want to bend the MVC framework a little to make it work a little different.
I want to create classes of HTML controls, for example, a class called "DropDownControl" that has a method "Render" that returns an html formatted string that is a custom drop down.
Then, I want to return that control from a controller's action.

I know I can use partial views but I want to use control objects so they can inherit from each other.

This way I can create a control called "HomeDropDownControl" that inhertis from the regular drop down control but only renders it a bit different.

What do you suggest?

Comment: No a MVC action cannot return such a DropDownControl. 
What you are looking for is an [EditorTemplate][1]


  [1]: http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Controller.Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.content(v=vs.118).aspx) method to return the HTML rendered by your control's `Render` method.

This is good if you want to return a single control to the client. Using [`Html.RenderAction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703541(v=vs.118).aspx) in a view to render multiple such controls isn't optimal since you might want to pass complex configuration objects to the control class and you probably don't want to go through the model binder for that.

I'm also assuming that you don't make separate calls to the server to get the markup for individual controls in a form, that's a not a good idea.